# formatting currency for google merchant center

Tags: php

to use approved google merchant, I need to send them the price in this format:

- 2,00 EUR must been written as 2.00 ou 2.
- 100 000,00 EUR must be written 100000 or 100000.00, and not 100,000.00, 100,000 or +100,000.
- Negatives values, like -20,14 EUR, must be written -20.14.

what I've got in my database actually is written like 100.000,00€

so to replace it, I've use:

```
  $total_price = substr(str_replace(",", ".", str_replace(".", "", $order->info['total'])),0, -6);
```

Which is quite bad in my opinion. any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NumberFormatter::parseCurrency](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php) to parse a string into a double and a currency using the current formatter.

Comment: thx, i'll dig into that. but the documentation doesn't look really strong

Comment: for those who come after, i've found that: which explain it better I think [Helpful PHP functions you may not have heard of](http://www.devlifeline.com/2013/10/helpful-php-functions-part-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

well regular expressions would help you keep things tidy, but you will still need to remove the dot you have lying around in there, and replacing the comma with a dot afterwards. once you have that, you can use

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $str);
```

to eliminate any currency labeling you saved. Note to future you: when developing software for multi-currency transactions, you should separate values from currencies. this way you can keep a decimal value in the db and keep the type of currency in tnother and not bother with this all together.

have fun! let me know if you need anything else

Comment: thanks, but still having to remove the dot and replace the comma isn't neater in my opinion.and thanks for me, it isn't multi-currency for this one

Comment: in mine either. saving a value you want to use as a decimal in a string format is a flaw imho. if NumberFormatter::parseCurrency works as expected, use that. but its still a patch :)

Comment: you 're right ; ). anyway  NumberFormatter::parseCurrency looks ike exactly what i wanted. thx